# Distributed testing with 2 CentOS VM machines and Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have 2 virtual machines with CentOS. Both of them with the same version of Jmeter installed and working. 
I am trying to run a distributed test, I have modified the jmeter.properties file (remote_host property and set the attribute #server.rmi.ssl.disable to true)  I can make a normal ping between the machines and it seems that jmeter has access to the machines working as "slave" or load genarator but I get the following error:

```
[root@01 bin]# jmeter -n -t jmeter_script1.jmx -r

Creating summariser <summary>

Created the tree successfully using jmeter_script1.jmx

Configuring remote engine: 10.111.2.4

    Starting remote engines

    Starting the test @ Tue Oct 15 14:12:17 CEST 2019 (1571141537956)

    Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 10.111.2.4; nested exception is:

    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)

    Remote engines have been started

    Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
```

**-------------Update 21/10/19.** 
I have removed the firewall with **sudo systemctl stop firewalld** in both machines (master & slave) but I get a new error message:

```
16:48:21 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.13.8
16:48:21 INFO: Starting with configs: ['test1.yml']
16:48:21 INFO: Configuring...
16:48:22 INFO: Artifacts dir: /root/taurus_container_scripts/2019-10-21_16-48-22.015788
16:48:22 WARNING: at path 'execution': 'execution' should be a list
16:48:22 INFO: Preparing...
16:48:22 WARNING: There is newer version of Taurus 1.13.9 available, consider upgrading. What's new: http://gettaurus.org/docs/Changelog/
16:48:24 INFO: Starting...
16:48:24 INFO: Waiting for results...
16:48:25 INFO: Waiting for finish...
16:48:27 WARNING: Please wait for graceful shutdown...
16:48:27 INFO: Shutting down...
16:48:27 INFO: Post-processing...
16:48:27 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:03
16:48:27 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:03
16:48:27 ERROR: Child Process Error: Empty results, most likely quick-test (JMeterExecutor) failed. Actual reason for this can be found in logs under /root/taurus_container_scripts/2019-10-21_16-48-22.015788
16:48:27 ERROR: JMeter STDOUT:
Created the tree successfully using /root/taurus_container_scripts/2019-10-21_16-48-22.015788/modified_requests.jmx
Configuring remote engine: 10.111.2.4
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Mon Oct 21 16:48:26 CEST 2019 (1571669306099)
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
Remote engines have been started
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
16:48:27 ERROR: JMeter log:
2019-10-21 16:48:26,902 ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:389) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.rconfigure(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:153) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:132) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.start(DistributedRunner.java:149) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:1089) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:991) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:563) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:253) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:396) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:186) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:219) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1867) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1750) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2041) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1410) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:560) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.readObject(HashTree.java:948) ~[jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1412) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:560) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.readObject(HashTree.java:948) ~[jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2177) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(UnicastRef.java:322) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.unmarshalParametersUnchecked(UnicastServerRef.java:629) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.unmarshalParameters(UnicastServerRef.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:338) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-10-21 16:48:26,917 INFO o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper
2019-10-21 16:48:26,917 ERROR o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
2019-10-21 16:48:26,918 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started
```

**------- Update 22-10-2019**
Dmitri's comment was really helpful. He was right and the jmeter-slave machine was missing the Concurrency Thread Group. After I installed it, no more error messages, the test is starting properly and I get the start/finish info in the slave machine [Jmeter Slave output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thuK3.png).

I am using Taurus in order to execute the test and even if the test is running in the slave machines, no data is comming to the Taurus GUI. The Taurus GUI is up and running all the time even if the test was finished already in the slave machine (I need to kill it to stop it). Am I missing another pluging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it's a networking or firewall issue.

1. Make sure to [bind the JMeter slave machine to the given network interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) like:

   ```
   ./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.111.2.4
   ```
2. Make sure to allow the following ports in the [firewall](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7)

   - the port you define as `server_port`, by default `1099`
   - the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
   - the ports you define as `client.rmi.localport`
3. Additionally you can force JVM to use [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) addresses by setting [`java.net.preferIPv4Stack` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) to `true`

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

Comment: **Point 1**: OK
**Point 2**: I have allowed the port 1099 already and I am using the following configuration: server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
then I dont need to worry about the ports server.rmi.localport and client.rmi.localport right?
**Point 3**: I have added the property java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true into the system.properties file in the JMeter server machine. 
I still get the same error.

Comment: You have to worry about the ports, disabling secure communication doesn't meet that master doesn't have to communicate with the slaves

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I have updated the post with extra information, do you have any syggestion to the situation where I am now? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to install (at least) [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) plugin on all slave machines. The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/). If there are any other plugins - you will need to install them as well. And if you're using external files (i.e. CSV files with the test data) you will need to copy them over to slaves

Comment: This worked Dmitri, thanks! I have an additional issue related to this, I have updated the post with the info, nice if you can advise me with it.